# (Correct) password not working

Tags: greeter, security

My (correct) password no longer works at login screen. At the login screen the password field accepts my password but does not allow me to log in. I just get the usual "field-shake" response and a blank field.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe somehow your global keyboard layout has changed. You think, you are typing the correct password, but it's not the one.

Comment: ...or the usual suspect: `Caps-Lock` enabled.

Comment: As an alternative, try switching to tty1 (`Ctrl + Alt + F1`) and see if you can login there. You can switch back to the GUI using `Ctrl + Alt + F7`.